# Convert value when mapping

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using **EF Code-First to an existing database** method and have a `IsActive` field in my database. The problem is that the field is `VARCHAR` when it should be a `boolean`. I can't change the Database schema.

Example value in the database are "Y" **(true)** or "N" **(false)**

When mapping, I want to convert those values to either true/false and keep my Entity class with the *boolean value*.

Is this possible?

My Entity and mapping classes are the following but I would like to change the `IsActive` field to be a boolean.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Employees");

        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID_Employee");
        this.Property(t => t.SSN).HasColumnName("sReference");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I found no other solution than this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709186/1053611

Comment: You use reverse engineering from database first, right ? So your class Employee is auto-generated and partial ?

Comment: Yes, correct, but I map them manually.

Comment: No sorry, I'm using EF Code-First to an existing database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from to string in database to boolean property Entity Framework 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708996/convert-from-to-string-in-database-to-boolean-property-entity-framework-4-1)

Comment: Yes, pretty much your only option is to make a new property whose getter returns `IsActive=="Y"?true:false` and optional setter with `IsActive=value?"Y":"N"`...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As others have pointed out you need two properties, but you may be interested to know that you can make one of the properties private and still map it to the database:

```
    private string isActive { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive == "Y"; }
        set { isActive = value ? "Y" : "N"; }
    }
```

If you are using EF6 you can use a custom convention in the `OnModelCreating` method to map the private property

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c =>
{
    //NB the syntax used here will do this for all entities with a 
    //private isActive property
    var properties = c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                             | BindingFlags.Instance)
                              .Where(p => p.Name == "isActive");
    foreach (var p in properties)
        c.Property(p).HasColumnName("IsActive");
});
```

References:

[Mapping private properties using custom conventions](http://romiller.com/2013/01/23/ef6-code-first-mapping-all-private-properties-using-custom-conventions/)

[Mapping private properties without custom conventions (before EF6)](http://romiller.com/2012/10/01/mapping-to-private-properties-with-code-first/)

**Edit:**

Here's another way of identifying the private properties that should be mapped to the database:

First add the column attribute to the private property:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column]
private string isActive { get; set; }
```

Then use the presence of that attribute to identify private properties in your `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c =>
{
    var properties = c.ClrType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(propInfo => 
           propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).Length > 0);

    foreach (var p in properties)
        c.Property(p).HasColumnName(p.Name);
});
```

Reference: [Mapping a private property with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21686896/150342)

Comment: Thank you. Knowing I can map a private property suddenly saves me a ton of code.

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent you from writing LINQ queries against the DB with things like `where x.IsActive` since that public property wouldn't be mapped?

Comment: @Mycroft Yes, it would. But if you keep all your data access code in a separate assembly, you might consider making the property `internal` rather than `private`.

Comment: What if I have bool? mapped but I need a private bool

Answer (score -2):

I have a solution to actually map the type meaning additional properties are not required. As I had a similar question for DateTimes, but easily convertible for bools:

[Is there a simple way using data annotations or a custom type to use a value stored as a string in SQL as a DateTime in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948645/is-there-a-simple-way-using-data-annotations-or-a-custom-type-to-use-a-value-sto/51983215#51983215)