# EF6 - UTC DateTime

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to specify Entity Framework to convert all DateTime in UTC (for azure database storage) ?

I would like that my model stay in local date time. I don't want to duplicate model datetime properties to have one in UTC (for EF) and another one in local (for my views, not mapped in EF).

Comment: You could write a custom saving changes method which uses reflection to find all datetime properties in objects that are going to be saved and convert them there...

Comment: Yes, that's ok for adding or updating to DB but not while reading from DB...

Comment: Similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/a/19377226/150342

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly possible. Either you'll live without it or you'll have to create some "helper" code (properties) in your classes/entities.