# Is it possible to add type conversion for assignments to a type?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, type-conversion

Meaning, is there anything I can do, so that when I try and assign a `short` to a `bool`, it invokes my custom type conversion from `short` to `bool`?

I have a DB first POCO model, and every true/false value in the entire data model generated off the DB of 250 tables is either `short?` or `short`. The original RDBMS didn't have the concept of a boolean value.

Now I can't just change all the shorts to bools because I get type conversion errors when querying the DbContext. I could substitute `bool` for a custom value type if I could get and set it's value without needing a `Value` property, e.g.

```
public struct BoolThatLikesShorts
{
...
}
```

and then use it like `BoolThatLikesShorts IsActive = (short)1;` and later on use it like

```
if (IsActive)
{
...
}
```

so that I we effectively have a complete `bool` equivalent.

Comment: I am not aware of any solution making this possible.. You can always write an extension method for short called ToBool(), but you probably know this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, wherever you place this code:

```
short foo = 4;
bool bar = (bool)foo; // Or even without cast.
```

You have your custom `TypeConverter` (or whatever) called, then **no, there is no such a easy way** of doing this.

However, there are some workarounds:

- Create a custom **valuetype** where it can be **implicitly** casted **to bool** and **explicitly from short** where `YourType` is a struct which has two cast operators defined within. So you could have

  ```
  bool bar = (YourType)(short)3;
  ```
- Create an extension, which will allow you to cast like this

  ```
  bool bar = ((short)3).ToBool();
  ```

Regarding to your updated answer, try peeking at this: [Convert value when mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping).

Comment: I can place an attribute on `foo`, but I can't change the assignment into a cast. This is for the automagic materialization of EF entity classes from DB query results.

Comment: @ProfK why don't you expand the question then explaning this and many other a thing about the technologies you are using, like EF, data mapping and so on?

Comment: I have expanded the question. I came up with a playfull experiment that might even work. A struct called `YesNo` with implicit cast operators to and from `bool` and `short`. I just don't like the name `YesNo`. Maybe `BOOL`?

Answer (score 1):

not implicitly but you could create an extension method

```
public static bool CustomBoolConversion( this short value )
{
    bool retVal;

    // custom implementation

    return retVal;
}
```

Usage:

```
short s = 1;
bool b = s.CustomBoolConversion();
```