# EF Code First Exception on non-nullable POCO property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a POCO that can't have any nullable properties, for various reasons, but the database I'm connecting to has null values for some of these corresponding properties, so I have to handle these and set them to something else in the property getter/setter logic. But I'm *still* getting...

```
Constraint Exception was unhandled by user code: The 'DischargeDate' property on 'Visits' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

...Here's my property logic....

```
 public class Visits
    {
        private DateTime _dischargeDate;
public DateTime DischargeDate
        {
            get {
                if (this._dischargeDate == null)
                {
                    this._dischargeDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                    return this._dischargeDate;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this._dischargeDate;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    this._dischargeDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._dischargeDate = value;
                }
            }
}
```

...and the DbContext is just straight forward, like...

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBContext(string connection)
            : base(connection)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Visits> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. It throws when the context is loaded. Or to be more specific, when I try to access the `DbSet<Visit>` Visits, like `_dbcontext.Visits;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` can't be null. So even though your setter is checking for null (which I'm surprised that comparison even passes), a property of DateTime **cannot** be set to null. So that's why EF is throwing that error and thus that logic won't work.

If the database is going to have nulls in it, you need your POCOs to have `DateTime?` as their property type so that EF can set it to null.

Simply doing:

```
public class Visits
{
    private DateTime _dischargeDate;

    public DateTime? DischargeDate
    {
        get {
            return _dischargeDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                this._dischargeDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                this._dischargeDate = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would work - `_dischargeDate` would never be null

Comment: That would do it. Or you could have a private `DateTime?` property mapped to the database and a public `DateTime` in the POCO that is not mapped http://stackoverflow.com/a/19377226/150342

Comment: @Colin - thanks for that pointer. That's probably a better (if more generic) explanation than mine.

Comment: @Colin - Yeah that's what I've done now, thanks guys

Comment: @Tim - Ok I see now, and I've used Colin's suggestion. Thanks for the quick response