# Use int Id for a bigint column in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We're using Entity Framework 6 to build a data layer on top of a legacy Sql Server database that has Id columns of type `bigint`.  We want to use `int` for our Id column types rather than `long`, and we're confident that the tables will never grow beyond the size limit of an `int`.

However, we're getting the following error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the
>   'System.Int32' type is not valid.

How can we achieve what we want without modifying the db column type?

Comment: Please, add some more info. When are you getting that mesasge? How does your model or code look like?

Comment: @JotaBe It's perfectly clear to me without more info...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to specify the DataType of the column in your `OnModelCreating` method for each model affected):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()   
    .Property(p => p.Id)   
    .HasColumnType("bigint");
```

If every Id in every model is mapped to a `bigint`, then you could use a custom convention:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<int>()
   .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
   .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("bigint"));
```

Another technique would be to use an abstract base class for all the Models that have a `bigint` `Id` (and this example shows it using data annotation instead of fluent API:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
   [Column(TypeName="bigint")]
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

References:

[Configuring the data type of a column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#1.10)

[Custom conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj819164.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#introducing)

Comment: Would it throw exception only in case of value exceeding int limits?

Comment: The last one did the trick for us, just putting the column type attribute on the model property:

`[Column(TypeName="bigint")]`

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
class DbEntity
{
    [Key]
    private Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int SmallerId { 
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(Id); }
    }
}
```

This strategy can be used for all sorts of mappings, like Yes/No to true/false, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping)

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to map an int field directly to a bigint column?

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but you could try the modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(x=>x.Id).HasColumnType("bigint"); method. however, the cast would still have to be done, I don't know if EF would really convert these values.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use **Int64** on your entity instead of trying to map to a data type that can't handle the maximum value in the database?

Comment: Simple = better!  _long_ will also work in place of Int64.