# Referencing column 'column' and referenced column 'Id' in foreign key constraint 'foreign_key' are incompatible

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to generate a migration using entity framework but I keep bumping into

```
Referencing column 'TaskId' and referenced column 'Id' in foreign key constraint 'FK_WorkerTaskTargetReference_WorkerTask_TaskId' are incompatible.
```

And I have no idea why.

My configuration seems to be correct:

```
public class WorkerTaskConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<WorkerTask>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Entity.Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(DataModelConstants.DEFAULT_FIELD_LENGTH);
            Entity.Property(x => x.UpdatedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(DataModelConstants.DEFAULT_FIELD_LENGTH);
            Entity.HasMany(x => x.Messages).WithOne(x => x.Task).HasForeignKey(x => x.TaskId).IsRequired();
            Entity.HasMany(x => x.TargetReferences).WithOne(x => x.Task).HasForeignKey(x => x.TaskId).IsRequired();
        }
}

  public class WorkerTaskTargetReferenceConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<WorkerTaskTargetReference>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            Entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(DataModelConstants.DEFAULT_FIELD_LENGTH);
            Entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(DataModelConstants.DEFAULT_FIELD_LENGTH);
        }
    }
```

But when I am applying my migration:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `WorkerTaskTargetReference` (
    `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `Type` int NOT NULL,
    `ReferencedId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `CreatedOn` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    `UpdatedOn` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    `CreatedBy` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `UpdatedBy` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `TaskId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_WorkerTaskTargetReference` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_WorkerTaskTargetReference_WorkerTask_TaskId` FOREIGN KEY (`TaskId`) REFERENCES `WorkerTask` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Referencing column 'TaskId' and referenced column 'Id' in foreign key constraint 'FK_WorkerTaskTargetReference_WorkerTask_TaskId' are incompatible.
```

Migration:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "WorkerTaskTargetReference",
        columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        Type = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        ReferencedId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        CreatedOn = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false),
        UpdatedOn = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false),
        CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 512, nullable: false),
        UpdatedBy = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 512, nullable: false),
        TaskId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
    },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_WorkerTaskTargetReference", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_WorkerTaskTargetReference_WorkerTask_TaskId",
                column: x => x.TaskId,
                principalTable: "WorkerTask",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_WorkerTaskTargetReference_TaskId",
        table: "WorkerTaskTargetReference",
        column: "TaskId");
```

And I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What datatype is `WorkerTask.Id` I expect its not a char(36)

Comment: In my entity model they are both guids

Comment: It is the sql statement that counts. Pls check WorkerTask.Id field's data type in mysql.

Comment: Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Id char(36) PK

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found out the solution.

My tables where with collation: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, while my database schema was with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

I changed my default server schema to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and it did the trick

Since they were chars, they are different because of schema

Answer (score 10):

The above answer did not solve it for me.  
In my case the `referencing` column data type was `int`, and that differed from the  `referenced` column that was `bigint` in the foreign key constraint.  By making the data types the same solved it for me.

Comment: Same was my case. Thanks

Comment: can you add the way you specified the data type in your migration ? (adding :type => :bigint to the add_reference function )

Comment: The question is tagged Mysql, so I had this problem in pure sql not entity-framework.  But if you need an answer try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266917/use-int-id-for-a-bigint-column-in-ef6.

Comment: for django i go to phpmyadmin and change ID filed to bigint. This problem for django > v.4, because they include bigint for all ID field and if you updated django, you have this problem. sorry for my eng

Comment: @JopaBoga Laravel also started doing the same with versions greater than 7 I believe.

Comment: In my case, the Attribute is also different.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting here for those whom the above answer might not helped them.
In my case it was different types of the attribute.
The referenced attribute was:
`storeId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER({ unsigned: true }) }`

While the referencing attribute was:
`storeId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }`

Answer (score 0):

With Typeorm 0.3+, both sides has to use the same `unsigned` option for solving the issue:

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
  id!: number;
```

```
  @ManyToOne(type => Test)
  test!: Relation<Test>;

  @PrimaryColumn({ unsigned: true })
  testId!: number;
```