# The expected type was 'System.Int64' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

On random occasions, users of our application are receiving this **invalid cast exception** The expected type was 'System.Int64' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'. This is not reproducible by us and it occurs on an **identity** (DataGrid.Id) field of our DataGrid model. The type in the database is `bigint` and the type in our model is `long`.

[image]

[image]

This seems to have started to occur after we started using `ToListAsync` instead of `ToList` on the entity.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return await _entitySet.ToListAsync();
}
```

I am not sure what is going on with these random requests throwing errors. I can provide a full stack trace if necessary, but the stack trace leads me to that line where it's throwing the exception, and it appears the data types match. This is usually a very random error and occurs once or twice every couple days. Can anyone suggest what may be occurring here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use int Id for a bigint column in EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266917/use-int-id-for-a-bigint-column-in-ef6)

Comment: It might help, but I have no idea how to guarantee that it works since we can't reproduce.