# How to query against non-mapped property in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

I am converting a mapped property's type via encapsulation using the process found here ([Convert value when mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping/19377226#19377226)). Like @Mykroft said, this prevents you from writing LINQ queries against the DB.

Using the example properties below, How can I tell Linq to Entities to use the IsActiveBool when writing the statement `db.Employee.Where(b => b.IsActive);` ?

```
[Column("IsActive")]
protected string IsActiveBool { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public bool IsActive
{
    get { return IsActiveBool == "Y"; }
    set { IsActiveBool = value ? "Y" : "N"; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using your simplistic example of `db.Employee.Where(b => b.IsActive);` You could write it like this:

```
db.Employee.ToList().Where(b => b.IsActive);
```

Keep in mind that this is going to pull back all rows in the `Employee` table and then filter on IsActive.  If you want SQL server to do the filtering for you (which you should because this isn't a good solution for a table of any real size) then you need to write it as:

```
db.Employee.Where(b => b.IsActiveBool == "Y");
```

Comment: This is not really a solution. It shows a bad practice approach to bringing everything into memory and an alternative that works for a narrow example but does not work for the OP's shown example.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, maybe I wasn't quite as explicit as I could be that it's not a good solution (I think that's pretty obvious), but that's the reason why I added the second option...

Comment: The second option is hardcoded though, this question is asking for a way to use abstract that logic out. I would assume the real world implementation is more complex then the simple example shown.

Comment: @TravisJ, no, you are assuming that's the objective, but it's only in the linked question.  I don't see anything in the current question that says `== "Y"` isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: "How can I tell Linq to Entities to **use the IsActiveBool** when writing the statement **db.Employee.Where(b => b.IsActive);**". I think it clearly states that although `IsActive` is being written in the statement, the underlying use should be `IsActiveBool`.

Comment: @TravisJ, You're still assuming the reason for the abstraction.  Maybe he just doesn't understand it.  In any case, I'm done.

Comment: @WyattEarp and @TravisJ, I don't want to use the string datatype for the boolean expression. I know I could use `IsActiveBool == "Y"` but I don't want to. TravisJ is correct in that my question is how can I use the IsActive boolean to perform the query