# ASP.NET - Transform data when loading it from database into entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Let's say we have first-names stored in all lower-case in a column in the `Person` table in the database, like: "john", "jane", "mary", etc.

When I load the first names into the `Person` entity (for example, to fulfill a query), I want to transform the first names so that the first letter is capitalized. So "John", "Jane" etc.

How can I do that using C#/Entity Framework. We also use Auto-Mapper.

I guess in general, how would I transform data from a table's record before loading the record into an entity?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377226/9338546) answer the data transformation part of your question?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please, show us your code and explain where did you get stuck?

Comment: You could create a `[NotMapped]` property that capitalizes the first char then pass that value around when needing to display results. This way there is no chance the data in the db itself will be effected.

Comment: string result = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(textToChange);

Answer (score 1):

you can add a notMapped property like:

```
        [NotMapped]
        public string NameTitleCase
        {
            get
            {
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(this.Name.ToLower());
            }
        }
```

remember add

```
using System.Globalization;
```