# Server Side Conversion with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, type-conversion

In my database I have a Date stored as a String, I would like to query a range of dates, server-side. Unfortunately it is a third-party application so I cannot change the schema.

Normally, in MySQL I would use `STR_TO_DATE()`, or `CONVERT()`.

How can I query a string date in MySQL using the Entity Framework when it doesn't support things like `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: optimally, change your database schema to hold a Date in that column.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a third party database and I cannot do that.

Comment: then you could pull from the database into memory, and cast your datetimes, and query that

Comment: I am aware of that, but if you review my question, I am looking to perform that server side. I am working with far too much data to pull the data to the client. So that won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe this solution is suitable for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708996/convert-from-to-string-in-database-to-boolean-property-entity-framework-4-1